# How to retrieve form.Value of []string type from echo.Context.MultipartForm()

Tags: go, multipartform-data, go-echo

I'm parsing a Multipart form from `echo.Context`. I retrieve the value of a slice (`[]string`) using `form.Value`. This returns a value with double braces. (eg. `[["this","something"]]`).

I tried reading from a non-slice (`string`) value and it returns correctly.

This parses the Form from `c echo.Context`

```
// Parse the Multipart form
    form, err := c.MultipartForm()
    if err != nil {
        return dataModel, err
    }
```

This retrieves value from the Form.

```
    product := form.Value["products"]
    if len(product) > 0 {
        dataModel.Product = form.Value["products"]
    }
```

dataModel defines a JSON struct as follows:

```
// LockRequest is the model for incoming lock requests
type LockRequest struct {
    Product     []string `json:"products" form:"products" query:"products"`
}
```

The value that `dataModel.Product` returns is `[["crm","something"]]`. It's creating a list of list probably. I want it to return `["crm","something"]`.

Expected: `["crm","something"]`
Actual: `[["crm","something"]]`

Comment: Include the code that produces the unexpected output.

Comment: Could you add the html part? What `enctype` do you use?

Comment: Something doesn't add up because (according to your struct definition) `LockRequest.Product` _is_ a `[]string`. In what context are you seeing the "slice of slices"?

Comment: Simply printing `form.Value["products"]` returns `[["crm","something"]]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I was curl-ing the data incorrectly.

`curl -XPOST -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' -F 'products=crm,something' http://localhost:50051/lockHandler`

instead of

`curl -XPOST -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' -F 'products="crm","something"' http://localhost:50051/lockHandler`

worked for me.